# How to Fetch Latest youtube Video's in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, youtube-api, laravel-5.4

I am using alaouy/Youtube package on my laravel 5.4 its fetching my all video's from my channel with that code

```
$videoList = Youtube::listChannelVideos('UC9PWIZ20pnEXgT1fT69bX8A', 50);
```

but its showing me old first i want to to fetch latest first what do i do
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In git repository of that package we can se this:

```
public function listChannelVideos($channelId, $maxResults = 10, $order = null, $part = ['id', 'snippet'], $pageInfo = false)
{
    $params = array(
        'type' => 'video',
        'channelId' => $channelId,
        'part' => implode(', ', $part),
        'maxResults' => $maxResults,
    );
    if (!empty($order)) {
        $params['order'] = $order;
    }
    return $this->searchAdvanced($params, $pageInfo);
}
```

That function seems to accept a third parameter "order"

So maybe this work:

```
$videoList = Youtube::listChannelVideos('UC9PWIZ20pnEXgT1fT69bX8A', 50, "date");
```

Comment: i just added 
$videoList = Youtube::listChannelVideos('UC9PWIZ20pnEXgT1fT69bX8A', 50, "date");
and its working no need to declare listChannelVideos function

Answer (score 0):

I ran the snippet you pasted and the videos do not appear to be in an order at all - the top few are 2016, then 2017, then 2016 again.

You can fetch the latest first by sorting the list:

```
$videoList = Youtube::listChannelVideos('UC9PWIZ20pnEXgT1fT69bX8A', 50);

usort($videoList, function ($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a->snippet->publishedAt) < strtotime($b->snippet->publishedAt);
});
```

Once the list is sorted, `$videoList[0]` will contain your most recent video

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying this package too and found that by using the search method you can loop through all of your videos and store the results in your database whilst capturing the publish date and other properties. From there you can use these records to easily sort by date or title etc and paginate through your videos. This also saves on multiple requests to the you tube api.

Anyone else taken that approach?